# How do I use the output of a command in a template in Puppet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, puppet

I am a puppet beginner, and we are trying to create a `passenger.load` module description file for Apache that contains the output of the command `passenger-config --root` such that the result looks like this:

```
 LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.14/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
 ...
```

To achieve this, we're using a template `passenger.load.erb` that contains this line:

```
LoadModule passenger_module <%= @passenger_root %>/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
...
```

The question now is: how do I set the variable `passenger_root`? I'd need something like `$passenger_root = "OUTPUT OF passenger-config --root"`, but as far as I know, puppet variables are more like constants.

Also the `passenger-config` command is made available by the puppet script itself (by installing passenger), so it is not available on the puppet master or at puppet compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot answer your question directly (no experience with Puppet), there are two alternatives:

1. Use the Phusion APT repository to install Passenger.
2. Use the Passenger tarball instead of gem. That way you control its exact path.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a way to do this directly with the way puppet works, so here are some alternatives (that can be modified or extended):

- Write a script that generates the file and have puppet execute it if the file is not there.
- Expose passenger_config_root as a facter fact and use it in your template